# Implementing a Dynamic Page with Next.js, TypeScript, Prisma and Postgres: How to Fetch Items by Category ID

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma

i use prisma + postgres, nextjs and typescript. so the question is how to create a page of a [category] where will be shown items which have realtion to category by id. i think i need to export async func from my categories.tsx which is shown below, but what should i do in this function - idk. my schema (maybe it is wrong in some aspects):

```
model Item {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug       String
  title      String
  about      String
  category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId Int
  img_path   String
}

model Category {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug     String
  title    String
  items    Item[]
  img_path String
}
```

**my funcs**

```
import prisma from './client';

export async function getCategories() {
  try {
    const categoriesFound = await prisma.category.findMany();
    return { categoriesFound };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}

export async function getItemsForCategories() {
  try {
    const itemsForCategory = await prisma.category.findMany({
      where: {
        items: {
          every: {
            id: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return { itemsForCategory };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}

export async function createCategory(category: any) {
  try {
    const categoryCreated = await prisma.category.create({ data: category });
    return { category: categoryCreated };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}

export async function getCategoryById(id: number) {
  try {
    const category = await prisma.category.findUnique({ where: { id } });
    return { category };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}

export async function deleteCategories() {
  try {
    const deleteCategories = await prisma.category.deleteMany();
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}

export async function updateCategory(id: number, data: any) {
  try {
    const updatedCategory = await prisma.category.update({
      where: { id },
      data,
    });
    return { category: updatedCategory };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}
```

**and my api reqs**

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import {
  createCategory,
  getCategories,
  getCategoryById,
  deleteCategories,
  updateCategory,
} from '@/prisma/categories';

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    try {
      const categories = await getCategories();
      res.status(200).json({ categories });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const data = req.body;
      const category = await createCategory(data);
      res.status(201).json({ category });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  } else if (req.method === 'DELETE') {
    try {
      await deleteCategories();
      return res.status(203).json({ message: 'Categories deleted' });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  } else if (req.method === 'PATCH') {
    try {
      const { id, data } = req.body;
      const updatedCategory = await updateCategory(id, data);
      res.status(200).json({ item: updatedCategory });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ error: 'Not found' });
  }
}
```

i tried to create function

```
export async function getItemsForCategories() {
  try {
    const itemsForCategory = await prisma.category.findMany({
      where: {
        items: {
          every: {
            categoryId: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return { itemsForCategory };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}
```

but it doesnt have any realtion to my dynamic page slug from category so idk what to do

Comment: is this nextjs13?

Comment: I have responded here: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/19476